# Does Oracle Apex 4 enable the following AJAX features? (ie without the dev writing the Javascript)

Tags: oracle-apex

1. Check client side that any 2 out of three fields have been completed before allowing submision of a form
2. Show/hide data capture fields based on the value of a check box (all client side)?

Comment: AJAX - Asynchronous JAVASCRIPT and XML. 
You can't have AJAX without Javascript. Any client-side / browser validation will require Javascript.
Are you asking whether Apex 4 generates the requisite JavaScript code for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex 4.0 has the new feature called [Dynamic Actions](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2010/03/trying-out-apex-40-dynamic-actions.html) that can perform Javascript and AJAX processing that you define declaratively, i.e. without having to write any (or much) Javascript.

**1) Check client side that any 2 out of three fields have been completed before allowing submision of a form**

You can create a Dynamic Action that fires on page submit, performs a test, and depending on whether the test returns TRUE or FALSE cancels the submit.  However, from my understanding of Dynamic Actions (which you can try out yourself at http://tryapexnow.com) in this example the condition to test would be a Javascript expression like this:

```
($v('P1_FIELD1') != '' && $v('P1_FIELD2') != '')
|| ($v('P1_FIELD1') != '' && $v('P1_FIELD3') != '')
|| ($v('P1_FIELD2') != '' && $v('P1_FIELD3') != '')
```

(I hope I have that syntax correct.)

**2) Show/hide data capture fields based on the value of a check box (all client side)**

This can be done without writing any Javascript, using a Dynamic Action.  Assuming the checkbox value is 'Y' when checked then the Dynamic Action's attributes would be something like:

```
Event:       Change
Item:        P1_CHECKBOX
Condition:   Equal To
Value:       Y
True Action: Hide Item(s)
  Items: P1_FIELD1, P1_FIELD2, P1_FIELD3
False Action: Show Item(s)
  Items: P1_FIELD1, P1_FIELD2, P1_FIELD3
```